# R Neural Networks - Iris Dataset Confusion Matrix

Tags: r

I don't how to figure the following: 
1.  Which 30 elements did it predicted ? 
2. I can't get the ConfusionMatrix working.

Any help appreciated.  Thank you.

```
library(nnet)
attach(iris)

library(caret)
set.seed(3456)
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p = .8,
                               list = F,
                               times = 1)

irisTrain <- iris[ trainIndex,]
irisTest  <- iris[-trainIndex,]

irispred <- nnet(Species ~ ., data=irisTrain, size=10)
predicted <- predict(irispred,irisTest,type="class")
```

output:

predicted <- predict(irispred,irisTest,type="class")

> predicted
>      [1] "setosa"     "setosa"     "setosa"     "setosa"     "setosa"     "setosa"             "setosa"
>    [8] "setosa"     "setosa"     "setosa"     "versicolor" "versicolor" "versicolor" "versicolor"
>   [15] "versicolor" "versicolor" "virginica"  "versicolor" "versicolor" "versicolor" "virginica" 
>   [22] "virginica"  "virginica"  "virginica"  "virginica"  "virginica"  "virginica"  "virginica" 
>   [29] "virginica"  "virginica"

Confusion Matrix errors, not sure what the should the 2nd argument be:

confusionMatrix(predicted, iris$Species)
Error in table(data, reference, dnn = dnn, ...) : 
  all arguments must have the same length

> confusionMatrix(predicted, irisTest, positive=1)
>   Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
>   Have you called 'sort' on a list?
>   confusionMatrix(predicted, iris, positive=1)
>   Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
>   Have you called 'sort' on a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument should be the reference classes which are in `irisTest$Species`. `irisTest` is the complete test data including all the other columns and `iris$Species` are the species for the whole data, not just the test set.

```
> confusionMatrix(data = predicted, reference = irisTest$Species)
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

            Reference
Prediction   setosa versicolor virginica
  setosa         10          0         0
  versicolor      0          9         0
  virginica       0          1        10

Overall Statistics

               Accuracy : 0.9667           

[...]
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I suppose we can't tell which 30 species it predicted ?  I wanted to make a comparison between the predicted and the test set but can't seem to see any matches , or am I comparing the wrong thing.

Comment: The predicted classes are already in your answer when you printed `predicted`. Then you just need to compare them to `irisTest$Species`. For example `data.frame(predicted, irisTest$Species)`

Comment: Thanks for the help. much appreciated.  Have you tried using to plot.nnet ?  --- I am not sure how to fix this error: plot.nnet(predicted)
Error in if (is.na(hid.struct[i + 1])) break : argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(hid.struct[i + 1]) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'

Comment: I can't tell where that `plot.nnet` function is from. If it is from [this blog post](https://beckmw.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/visualizing-neural-networks-in-r-update/) you need to follow the steps described there to install the function from Github. In any case, you have to plot the *model object* `irispred` and not the numeric vector `predicted`.

Comment: PS: I meant you have to follow the procedure described there for plotting the model (since you have apparently installed the function already).

Comment: Thanks.  I got it working.  This is the link:                                        library(devtools)
source_url('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fawda123/7471137/raw/466c1474d0a505ff044412703516c34f1a4684a5/nnet_plot_update.r')

#plot each model
install.packages("scales")    ---------  I will post another question for the weights.